# Export road system to CSV file

Tags: qgis, mbtiles

I'm using QGIS to extract coordinates of a road network.
Concretely, I downloaded a mbtiles file from Internet and loaded the file into QGIS like following:

[image]

Then I tried to export the layer `transportation` to a `csv` file. However, I didn't see the coordinates (latitude, longitude) of the road.

[image]

I tried to add the coordinates by using `Vector > Geometry Tool > Export\Add geometry column`, but it doesn't produce the coordinates. 
[image]

Furthermore, in the attribute table, I can see `_row` and `_column`. 
How can I obtain the latitudes and longitudes for the road system?

Comment: There are expressions to retrieve geographical properties of your road network ... it all depends on what you want to get ... What is your QGIS version ? Do u want to have the coordinates of all vertices of your roads network ? it can be quite 'heavy' ...

Comment: It's QGIS 64 bit, 2.8.16.
What I want is to quantize the roads myself.
Currently, I guess a road is divided into several segments but in one non-uniform manner and I want to make the segments uniform. To do it, I think I'll need to obtain all the coordinates.

Comment: i wasn't sure what format was "mb_tiles" ... if your starting point is an image format (**raster**) your task is gonna be "tough" i fear ... if it is vector data that should be possible depending on the complexity of your dataset (ofc) ...

Comment: I think it is vector data because when loading, I have to do `vector > vector tile reader`. Do you have any suggestion in computing coordinates?

Comment: if you download something 'locally' i think it will be easier to query it because your dataset looks rather large ... then u have operators to access vertices of all your objects ... In your data structure you have to find a clear id **by road section** (it doesn't look obvious in the screenshot u joined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lines (and polygons) do not have one coordinate. Lines have at least two. The number of numpoints (some call them vertex) (and their coordinates) depend on the complexitiy of the lines.

In QGIS it the [WKT-Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) is commonly used. You can export any layer to a .csv including the geometry as WKT:

[image]

There are also other options such as "XY", "XYZ", but as I know they don't work for lines.

I want to add two notes:

1. Your .csv might become very large as your road network seems to be pretty complex
2. As many users open up .csv files with Excel, keep in mind that Excel will cut off cells with a String (WKT-Information) [grater than ~32000 signs](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3). There is no issue though opening it with a common text editor or QGIS.

---

In case you want the centroid of each line, you can use the following expression and add it as new field:
`x(centroid($geometry))` and `y(centroid($geometry))`

In case you want the start and end points of each line, you can use this expression and add it as new field:
 `x(start_point( $geometry))` and  `y(start_point( $geometry))` as well as  `x(end_point( $geometry))` and  `y(end_point( $geometry))`

Comment: I tried `AS_XY` before but it turns out that only the option `AS_WKT` works.
Thanks.