# Where are all the layers in QGIS 3.14

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

Some months ago, I had an old version of QGIS (I don't remember exactly the version, probably < 3), and when I opened an mbtiles file, it was easy to find all the layers, including transportation, place, water, etc. I was also able to export a specific layer to csv. (See my [previous post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/319351/export-road-system-to-csv-file))

Now with QGIS 3.14, it is no longer able to see the layers, and of course I'm not able to export data to csv files (see figure below).
How can I get back the layers as before?

[image]